# CDC Temperature Requirement for Vaccines

Tags: vaccine, home-medical-equipment, refrigerate-refrigeration

We're facing a problem within several health facilities regarding vaccines storage.

The [CDC requirement for vaccines](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/pubs/pinkbook/downloads/vac-storage.pdf) is to be kept in the 36°F - 46°F (2°C - 8°C) range, or equivalently, in the 41+-5°F (5+-3°C) range under cold chain. Out of this range, the CDC and the manufacturers claim the efficiencies of their vaccines get reduced.

Most commercial options available for medical refrigerators are compressor-based, which operate with an on-off controller, turning on the compressor when the temperature has reached a temperature setpoint. In practice, this makes the temperature oscillate between 41+-2°F (5+-1°C).

We set an alarm for any increase in temperature, so we can prevent any trouble that can happen, since when the measured temperature reaches 46°F (8°C) we have to report the incident to our managing authorities.

Hence, we set an alert at 44°F (7°C), leaving us a narrow 2°F (1°C) from the expected maximum of 43°F (6°C) due to the compressor oscillations.

And if we add the 1°F (0.5°C) measuring uncertainty required by the CDC, we run out of range for any alert.

I have reviewed other options but most of the medical refrigerators with 36°F - 46°F (2°C - 8°C) rating work with a control resolution of +-2°F (+-1°C), leaving us with the narrow 2°F (1°C) for alerting.

Question is, have you faced, or know somebody who have faced, this problem before? Should we move from the standard medical refrigerators rating into another type of equipment? How we are supposed to stick with the commercial range if most -if not all- equipment have such huge variations?.

Comment: Surely you can set your alarm set point to a lower temperature - giving you more leeway? The CDC recommends pharmaceutical grade fridges, which generally have excellent temp control. You should note that opening and closing the fridge to get vaccines out is going to cause temp fluctuations that will likely exceed the max, so required reporting at every measured report is a stupid policy.

Comment: It can't be so low, since it's very close to the freezing point!. So, my question is what to do with this, since most commercial equipment have compressors with +-2 F, which, I agree, leads to bad things. But suppose somebody says the vaccines do not work because the cold chain is broken. So, it is a hard issue.

Comment: Temperature isn't the only measurement that matters. Time matters equally. A minute or two barely above the upper limit isn't even going to change the temperature of the vial, much less the temperature of its contents. Surely your requirements take that into account.